# Opportunity Event Trigger not working

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm trying to get a trigger to go off that would create an Event on an Opportunity.
The trigger should go off when a box is checked (Create_Calander_Event__c) but the trigger isn't working at the moment, does anything stand out to anyone on this?

```
trigger CreateEvent on Opportunity (after update) {

    List<Event> EventInsert = new List <Event>();

    for (opportunity o : trigger.New) {
        if(o.Create_Calander_Event__c == true ) { 
            event e = new event();
            e.subject = o.Name;
            e.ActivityDateTime = date.today();         
            e.StartDateTime =o.hire_start_date__c ;
            e.EndDateTime = o.hire_start_date__c;
            e.WhatId = o.Id;
            e.WhoId = o.Contact__c;
            e.OwnerId = '005w0000003D6Mw';
            EventInsert.add(e);
        }//End If
    }//End For
}//End Trigger
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not inserting you list.  You add the new events to the list, but never insert it.

```
trigger CreateEvent on Opportunity (after update) {

    List<Event> EventInsert = new List <Event>();

    for (opportunity o : trigger.New) {
        if(o.Create_Calander_Event__c == true ) { 
             event e = new event();
             e.subject = o.Name;
             e.ActivityDateTime = date.today();         
             e.StartDateTime =o.hire_start_date__c ;
             e.EndDateTime = o.hire_start_date__c;
             e.WhatId = o.Id;
             e.WhoId = o.Contact__c;
             e.OwnerId = '005w0000003D6Mw';
             EventInsert.add(e);
        }//End If
    }//End For
    insert EventInsert;
}//End Trigger
```

On a side note, you may want to alter the code to check for only Opportunities where that checkbox was just checked.  As it is this will create an event on the Opportunity each time it is edited if that box is checked, even if there was already an event created.  So basically if you check the box, the event will be created.  If you then edit that record 3 more times, nothing to do with the checkbox, it will create 3 more events, since the checkbox is still true.  I don't think this is what you want.  You might want to alter your If statement to something like this

```
if(o.Create_Calander_Event__c && !trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).Create_Calander_Event__c) { 

}
```

This checks for Opportunities where the checkbox was previously unchecked, and is now checked.

Comment: Thanks, I've been staring at that for an hour and don't know how I missed that

Comment: No worries, happens to us all from time to time.  Fresh eyes on it always helps  :)